# Spring Cloud Kubernetes Loadbalancer issue with Spring Boot 2.6.6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-kubernetes, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

I am using spring boot 2.6.6 and spring cloud 2021.0.2 version with spring cloud kubernetes loadbalancer and spring cloud kubernetes all.

But I am getting error Application failed to start below are the dependencies

```
<properties>
   <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
   <spring-boot.version>2.6.6</spring-boot.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-all</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-kubernetes-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Error:

2022-05-24 01:05:51.399 ERROR 14884 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.cloud.loadbalancer.config.LoadBalancerCacheAutoConfiguration$DefaultLoadBalancerCacheManagerConfiguration.defaultLoadBalancerCacheManager
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

Process finished with exit code 1

Please if someone can help to understand what is the going wrong here.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks !!

Comment: spring cloud kubernetes 1.x is not compatible with boot 2.6, spring cloud 2021.0

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks for your comment. Yeah you are right with the versioning part.
And I'm not sure if supporting versions are released or renamed or I'm missing something here to make it working again. 

Link : 
loadbalancer : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes-loadbalancer

starter-all : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-all

I see the latest is 1.1.10-RELEASE

Do you know by chance what all kubernetes dependencies will work with spring boot 2.6.X and spring cloud 2021.0.X

Comment: Use boot dependency plug-in to manage spring cloud versions

Comment: You can also use start.spring.io to generate a pom with compatible dependencies.

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek : kubernetes dependencies are not available to select.

Comment: @spencergibb : sure that a good point, but my issues is which kubernetes version or dependency to be used with spring boot 2.6.6 or later

Comment: @Vish that sounds like a different question.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Supported-Versions#supported-releases

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @spencergibb thanks very much for the wiki link which gives more clarity on the compatibility matrix and samples along with it… Appreciating your time & response..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanking all to share your views via comments. I have figured out the answer.

I see below dependency seems to be working fine with latest spring boot 2.6.6 or 2.7.0

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

It seems this is similar to what below ones use to provide, such as config or load balancer etc. certainly the dependencies are renamed as you can see.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```